# MySQL no timezone tables - need to compare Europe/London to UTC

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with a table that has a DATETIME type field which gets updated after the PHP datetime default timezone is set:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

mysql_query("UPDATE mytable SET status='$status', statusupdated='$date' WHERE id='$id'");
```

I need to create a query that gets all the results after a certain ($landing) time (UTC):

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE CONVERT_TZ(`statusupdated`, 'GMT', 'UTC') > $landingtime");
```

However the database doesn't have any timezone tables so the above doesn't work.

How can I standardise the query so I can compare `statusupdated` against UTC?

NOTES:

**I am unable to edit the database data types as this is an external database. Thanks**

**To simplify the question I have simplified the  code (I know about SQL injection etc) and I know about the deprecated functions. Thanks.**

Comment: But did you know mysql_query is deprecated? Use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Can you have any impact on any code? Can you have PHP convert everything to UTC instead of Europe/London and save that to your db?

Comment: Keep all the date times in UTC formats in DB & convert into different timezone in program back ends. This can manage for different timezone users..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out how to do this.

I can convert `@@session.time_zone` to `'+00.00'`. Lovely!

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE CONVERT_TZ(`date`, @@session.time_zone, '+00:00') > $landingtime");
```